# When will I be able to post questions on my Stack Overflow account again?

Tags: support

I have gotten stuck in a great problem, I am not able to post questions on this site. I have read the article that whenever a user deletes their questions then Stack Overflow  blocks that user from asking any question.
I was new to this site and did not know about this policy that you should not delete your own questions. Only when I was blocked from asking any questions on it, did I come to know about this policy. I accept all my faults. Could anyone tell me when I will able to post questions on this site again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're no longer blocked. Up-votes you received after posting this have lifted the block. *I'm fine with that*, because most of the 'trouble' you got into was prior to us drastically improving how the block system works - you would have had the benefit of being slowed down dramatically with additional help put in front of you, which I think would have helped.

You *do* know how to ask decent questions, so - enjoy :) Just be sure to continue to put thought into them, and learn from the help that editors provide. For folks that pay close enough attention, the site tends to make writers better at writing.

Comment: "You do know how to ask decent questions" - I visited OPs profile and looked at two questions; both improperly used code snippets for Android-related things, had basic formatting problems, and other issues that makes them fall below "decent" IMO. Simply look at the first revision of this question for an example. So I'd have to disagree with your assesment that this is a good thing.

Comment: Again i have blocked to ask any questions on these site...When i posted these question than for some time i have unblocked but yet now they blocked me again.please help me :)

Comment: @l4mpi Literary works of art? No, but mostly clear and answerable describe the ones I looked at (also evidenced by the quality of the answers).

Comment: @TimPost ..Please let me know that when i will unblock to ask any question..??

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha You'll need to [contact us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) - you're very close to the threshold for being blocked, which is why you saw the block lift for a short time. In the meantime, go back to your _highest_ voted questions, fix _as many spelling and grammar mistakes_ as you can - a few more up votes would probably put you back over the line.

Comment: @TimPost ...Sir i want to ask the only one question to you that why the people down votes question continuously?? If the have any problem regarding to the question than why not they edit and update it properly..I observes many time that whenever a new user or me want too ask any question on these site than...people continuously down voted it...it's not fair.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha: downvotes are treated just the same as upvotes, in that they are both indicators of low-quality or high-quality questions. They are not personal and shouldn't be taken as such. At the scale Stack Overflow has, it is very difficult to fix up the thousands of questions asked per day, so the asker needs to put some effort into asking a question that's clear and answerable.

Comment: ok Sir thanks.. @Qantas94Heavy :)

Comment: I am having the same trouble as the qustioner is there anyway to undelet qustions?